# right and left derivatives of a cfg from parse tree?

Tags: automata, context-free

i just want to double check with what i concluded from this parse trees.

> ```
>        A
>       / \
>      /   \
>     B      C
>    / \    / \
>   0   D  D   E
>          |   |
>          0   1
> ```

from the above tree i get right derivation to be

> A -> C
>
> C -> D|E
>
> E -> 1
>
> D -> 0

and the left derivation as

> A -> B
>
> B -> 0|D
>
> D -> 0

i just want someone to proof check for me. and tell me if am wrong somewhere. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you wrote are not derivations, they are grammars.

The leftmost derivation in your case is $A \to BC \to 0DC \to 0DDE \to 0D0E \to 0D01$. I'll leave you to figure out the rightmost derivation.

Comment: ohh i think i got it now. so the right derivation would be; $A \to BC \to BDE \to 0DDE \to 00DE \to 00D1$  and why didn't we drive the D first in the left most derivation 0D0E part?

Comment: Any derivation must end with 00D1, which are the symbols in the leaves read left to right. Please review the definitions once again.